# I'm getting 0 results in my search whenever i have the search input area prefilled

Tags: javascript, forms, search

I'm having trouble getting search results in my form whenever I use js to pre-fill the input field. I was wondering if their was a workaround this.

I'm using this code -

```
value="Keywords" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Keywords') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Keywords';}" />
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you doing anything else? Just having the onfocus and onblur isn't enough, you need to actually trigger the events.

Comment: Are you prefilling the input with the HTML5 placeholder attribute? If so, are you testing this in a browser that fully supports the placeholder spec?

Comment: I suppose, that code you posted have no relation to search *results*.

Comment: I encourage the use of line breaks which keeps it from feeling like I'm reading it through a key hole.

Comment: Robert - the search form looks for keywords, so im guessing that the reason why i get no results back is because the form thinks that the pre-filled text are keywords it supposed to look for.

Comment: mwilcox - no one else seemed to have a problem, that comment really answered my question. Thanks for the trolling.

Comment: kirilloid - that was just to show you what I was using to pre-fill the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever this issue is, it is related to some other code that you have not yet shared with us (without seeing how you're processing the form, we can only speculate what might be causing the problem).

Below is a jsFiddle example that shows that the code you posted works perfectly. This is only proof that something else in your code is causing the error.
http://jsfiddle.net/pULAS/

I would recommend taking a good hard look at the server side code you're using to read and process the form, as the culprit is likely in there.